# WCF C# call base address from browser avoid the method name

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm going to write a little standalone webservice for an application to allow other applications in my pc to read the XML published from the webservice.
I've made an interface `IMachineData` as follow

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)] 
public interface IMachineData
{
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)] 
    XElement GetData();
}
```

and the linked class as follow

```
public class MachineData : IMachineData
{
    public XElement GetData()
    {
        return MyBridge.GetXML();
    }
}
```

The app.config is configured with a localhost on port 5000 and I start the host from my winform as follow:

```
Type serviceType = typeof(MachineData);
host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
host.Open();
```

after if I write on my browser the address

```
http://localhost:5000/GetData
```

everything works well. I can see the XML in the browser.
Well... here starts my problems. The application (third parts) needs an address like `http://localhost:5000/` without the "GetData".
I tried all the configurations without success. 
Has someone an idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are hosting your WCF service, you may be able to override the default page when accessing the service.  Check out this [post](https://cgeers.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/replacing-the-you-have-created-a-service-message/).

An overview of the process is as follows:

- You'll want to decorate the GetData() function as an Unmatched Message Handler.  This requires you to return either void or a `Message` type:

  ```
  [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
  public interface IMachineData
  {
      [OperationContract(Action="*", ReplyAction="*")]    
      Message GetData();
  }
  ```
- The GetData function returns a custom Message object that overrides
  the base Message:

  ```
  public class DataMessage : Message
  {
      private readonly MessageHeaders _headers;
      private readonly MessageProperties _properties;

      public DataMessage()
      {
          this._headers = new MessageHeaders(MessageVersion.None);
          this._properties = new MessageProperties();
      }

      public override MessageHeaders Headers
      {
          get { return this._headers; }
      }

      public override MessageProperties Properties
      {
          get { return this._properties; }
      }

      public override MessageVersion Version
      {
          get { return this._headers.MessageVersion; }
      }

      protected override void OnWriteBodyContents( XmlDictionaryWriter writer )
      {
          writer.WriteStartElement("HTML");
          writer.WriteStartElement("HEAD");
          writer.WriteStartElement("BODY");
          writer.WriteStartElement("SPAN");
          writer.WriteString("This is a test page.");
          writer.WriteEndElement();
          writer.WriteEndElement();
          writer.WriteEndElement();
          writer.WriteEndElement();
      }

  }
  ```
- You will also need to update the config file to disable the service
  metadata:

  ```
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="noMetadata">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  ```
- One small hurdle I could not overcome... I still had to have a
  service name in the base address URL, or else the default landing
  page would not show.

  ```
      <services>
          <service name="MachineDataSvc.HelloWorld" behaviorConfiguration="noMetadata">
              <endpoint address="" 
                                  binding="customBinding" 
                                  bindingConfiguration="landingPage"
                                  contract="MachineDataSvc.ILandingPage" />
              <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8740/Service" />
                  </baseAddresses>
              </host>
          </service>
      </services>
  ```

Navigating to this link would show the custom landing page, that could theoretically be tweaked to return the XML you need:

http://localhost:8740/Service/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16752060)

Comment: Updated to show the details of a possible solution.

Comment: Hello and thanx for your answer. I've seen the link you sayd before, but my target is write in the browser an address like:
http://localhost:8740
and not as yours http://localhost:8740/Service/
Thanx